# Where primitives data types are available in java?

Tags: java

If they are not in class then where the data types are available under which package????How we are using them?

If they are comes under java.lang package then there should be some classes for them?

If they are built in so where are they?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html - The Java tutorials are quite thorough, you should read them.

Answer (score 1):

they are built in in the language:

int, long, float, double, char, byte, boolean, short

For some comfort, such conversions, there are classes,too:
They all are in the java.lang package:
Integer, Long, Float, etc.

Examples:

```
int a = 3;
a++;

Integer aObj = new Integer(266666);
```

Comment: If we are not importing any of the package so how we are using it?Means they are not available inside any of the class?

Comment: you dont habe to import primitive types, just use it. they are built in.

Comment: Sorry but i have a doubt...If they are built in then where are they inside any class or somewher else???

Answer (score 1):

Read the specifications here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2

> There are two kinds of types in the Java programming language: **primitive types** (§4.2) and **reference types** (§4.3). There are, correspondingly, two kinds of data values that can be stored in variables, passed as arguments, returned by methods, and operated on: primitive values (§4.2) and reference values (§4.3).

There is a third type as well named `null`:

> There is also a special null type, the type of the expression null (§3.10.7, §15.8.1), which has no name.

Primitive types are special data types and not part of any package or class. Though there are related wrapper types e.g. Integer, Long, Boolean etc which are placed in `java.lang` package.

Answer (score 0):

They are not class, and hence they does not exists in any package.

That's the design of Java.

Primitive types includes boolean, byte, char, short, int, long, float and double (I think I haven't missed any right? :P )

All of them have a corresponding wrapper under java.lang.  For example, Byte, Character, Integer etc.

Comment: ya boolean and short too! :P adding it